# How to design away the need of Android Contexts

Tags: android, singleton, sharedpreferences, android-context

I have several classes in my application that uses the `Context` object to access SharedPreferences and serialize files. Simply put, I want to know how to "design away" the Context.

The background to why I want to do this is because:

1. The classes should be created in the `onCreate()` method of a `Fragment` (and the Context is not decided at this point)
2. It's just plain ugly to pass around the Context all the time. Especially since I use Singleton-reminding instantiation of these classes (Don't judge, ***please***)
3. The specific context isn't really needed here, so it should be possible to design away... (What I mean is that I only need the Application Context)

An example of why this is ugly is my `Cache` object. It holds cached values downloaded from 1-5 different sources decided at runtime.

```
public static Cache getInstance(Context context) {
    if(instance == null) {
        instance = new Cache(context);
    }
    return instance;
}
```

When later using this object, it needs to read a `SharedPreference` which needs the `Context`, so it has to be passed around every single time I want to get an instance of the `Cache`.

So how can I get rid of these ridiculous contexts? Using the `Application Context` should be just fine... I guess that the problem can be boiled down to something like "How do I get a SharedPreferences object" in an object without a specific Context?"

Answer (score 1):

> I guess that the problem can be boiled down to something like "How do
>   I get a SharedPreferences object" in an object without a specific
>   Context?"

Using the `Application Context`. For this purpose you can subclass Application, registering it in your AndroidManifest file, and have a method to retrieve it from every where, like a singleton

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the static `getContext()` method on the Application object before and I think it's slightly ugly and I wasn't sure that it was "Risk free" and correct. I was just about to implement it when I found this: https://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=1218 which basically says that the `Application` object in Android can be treated as a Singleton and that I should place my own Singletons inside that object.

It's essentially the same as @Blackbelt 's solution, but gives a slightly nicer vibe!